# How to transform data from shape (256, 60) to (96, 64) for my machine learning model?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, signal-processing

I am trying to work with the VGG network and I need to feed in the spectrogram to the model so that it uses the CNN to make predictions. So the NumPy array that I have right now is of shape (256, 60) where there are 256 frequencies for 60 different time stamps. I need to feed in the vggish model in the shape of (96, 64). Where 96 represents the number of time stamps and 64 represents the number of frequencies. So basically I need to reduce the frequencies from 256 to 64 and increase the timestamps from 60 to 64.

```
temp = gitSpectrogram[:, windowTimeGit - 30:windowTimeGit + 30]
```

If temp is the NumPy array that I need to change how do I do this task?

Comment: OpenCV's ```resize``` functionality may be able to help you. [Link](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

Comment: You can't really increase the number of timestamps without making up data that isn't there.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys is there a way if I want to add null or 0 values for the data that I don't have?

Comment: What CNN function are you using and what does the documentation of that function say?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys I am using the VGG model. The input needs to be in the form of (96, 64). But I have the best data in the form of (256, 60). SO need to change it just in order to make it work. I am not really worried that much on how good the results will be. I just want it to run right now.

Comment: Please, provide actual import statements and names of functions.